# If we accelerate experimental apparatus and the object to be measured at the same acceleration, do we obtain the same measurement as we do in rest?

Tags: experimental-physics, symmetry, inertial-frames, observers, foundations

It is a fact of nature that measurement it is the same in all inertial frames.
But if we accelerate experimental apparatus and the object to be measured at the same acceleration, do we obtain the same measurement as we do in rest?

Answer (score 2):

> Do we obtain the same measurement as we do at rest ?

No. Attach an object of mass $m$ in a spaceship accelerating at rate $a$ to a spring balance and the balance will show  force of $ma$, whereas if the spaceship is at rest or is moving with constant velocity the balance will show a force of zero.

This shows that acceleration is absolute, not relative i.e. we can detect acceleration with local measurements. Note, however, that the [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) in general relativity tells us that a constant rate of acceleration is indistinguishable from a uniform gravitational field.

Comment: In your experience is the spring who is accelerating the object. but If someone is holding the object  of mass $m$ in the spring at the spaceship we would not  detect a force. In your experiment  you are  not accelarating the apparatus and the object independetely, the accelartion of the object is due to the measurement...

Comment: what I am asking if you accelarate the object and the apparatus independetly if we obtain the same physics

Comment: @amiltonmoreira If you are measuring relative to an accelerating frame of reference then the forces that you measure acting on an independently accelerating object will no match its apparent acceleration. So you will not see the same results as you would if measuring relative to an inertial reference frame.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your question is that you really can't

> accelerate the object

And still do the same experiment with the object. As soon as you, additionally to performing the experiment, accelerate the object, you will essentially perform a different experiment.

Of course you could be more precise now and say "Well, what I mean is that additionally to all the other forces that are present in the experiment, in the accellerated case there should be an additional force of exactly the amount to have the object see the same accelleration".

Sadly, this definition of how the experiment should be different can't easily be carried over to the case where we with quantum mechanics, or electric fields. What does it mean to accellerate an electric field?
You would have to come up with a description of how exactly the electric field ought to be different. If you let it as is, then you certainly won't see the same physics:

I will borrow the example of @gandalf61:

Take the object of mass $m$ in the spaceship, but additionaly, place a charge on it. When the spaceship accelerates with $a$, the experiment would show a force $-ma$, whereas if the spacehsip is at rest, the balance will show a force of zero. According to your initial proposition, you change the experiment by additionally adding a spurious force of exactly size $ma$ that acts on the mass. Now, the balance will show zero for all values of a.

But you still do have an accelerating charge now. And accelerating charges produce electromagnetic waves, that are radiated away perpendicular to the direction of acceleration. You will see this light only in the accelerating case, and by this way you can tell in which frame you are.

Comment: to detect electromagenetic waves  you need a charge. I am not sure but I think if you have to accellerated charges  accelarating at the same rate the fields  produced by these charges on each other will cancel. Am I wrong?

Comment: I can't tell you for sure, but I doubt it.